# Using moment generating function to prove Poisson distribution.

Tags: probability-theory

[See question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM5bN.png)

So I have a pair of dependent random variables, $Y\big|X$. From the question the pmf of $Y\big|X$ is just $x\sim \text{Bin}(x,p)$. So the m.g.f of $Y\big|X$ is $(1+ p(e^t -1)^x$ (from the m.g.f of binomial $(x,p)$. I am  not sure how to obtain m.g.f of $Y$ from here. Help please, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Understand that the MGF of a sum of a fixed number of independent and identically distributed random variables $W_1, W_2, \ldots, W_n$, each with MGF $$M_{W_i}(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tW_i}]$$ is simply the product of their individual MGFs; i.e., if $$(Y \mid X) = \sum_{i=1}^X W_i,$$ then $$M_{Y \mid X}(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{t(W_1 + \cdots + W_X)} \mid X] = \prod_{i=1}^X \operatorname{E}[e^{tW_i} \mid X] = \prod_{i=1}^X M_{W_i}(t) = (M_{W}(t))^X.$$  It follows that the unconditional expectation is the MGF of the marginal distribution of $Y$; i.e., $$M_Y(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tY}] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[e^{t(W_1 + \cdots + W_X)} \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[M_{Y \mid X}(t)] = \operatorname{E}\left[(M_W(t))^X\right].$$  But since we may write this as $$\operatorname{E}[e^{X \log M_W(t)}] = M_X(\log M_W(t)),$$ we now can see how to do the computation:  In your case, $W \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$, and $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$.  Why is $W$ Bernoulli and not binomial?  Because the sum of IID Bernoulli variables is binomial, and $Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(X,p)$; hence we need each $W_i$ to be a Bernoulli variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't quite understand the 4th line of your equations "It follows that the unconditional expectation is the MGF f the marginal distribution of Y....."